# Puppeteer is leaving a massive amount of chrome defunct processes

Tags: php, node.js, google-chrome, puppeteer

I'm currently using an adaptation of puppeteer for PHP called [puphpeteer](https://github.com/zoonru/puphpeteer). It works pretty well, using a library called [rialto-php](https://github.com/rialto-php/rialto) (deprecated, but it still works very well) that it's able to manage Node resources from PHP which is pretty neat. I'm using the latest update that uses puppeteer 20, PHP 8.2 and Node 16.20.

But I cannot find the way to understand why for every call it creates like 6 chrome processes and they all end defunct when the process ends

```
 614 ?        00:00:00 chrome <defunct>
  628 ?        00:00:00 chrome <defunct>
  629 ?        00:00:00 chrome <defunct>
  682 ?        00:00:00 chrome <defunct>
  696 ?        00:00:00 chrome <defunct>
  718 ?        00:00:00 chrome <defunct>
```

I'm also using latest chrome-stable with puppeteer with these arguments

```
$browser = $puppeteer->launch([
                'executable_path' => 'google-chrome-stable',
                'args' => ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox'],
        ]);
```

Here is a gist with the function, it simply gets the iFrame URL from my page.
https://gist.github.com/SirLouen/8c274ae588eece30a14b43e7af4880f8

Do you have any ideas on how I could identify the culprit of this issue?

The first thing is that I'm thinking of transforming this code to JS and testing it straight on the original puppeteer library, but I've commented with other people using puphpeteer and they are not finding this defunct issue.

Comment: Close your browser in a `finally` block.

Comment: @ggorlen following your advice I've modified the code accordingly
https://gist.github.com/SirLouen/8c274ae588eece30a14b43e7af4880f8
But I can't see anything special in the output and the same defunct processes keep popping in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the equivalent code in JS running straight from node. It took me a while because I've never used node before and I had to read docs.

https://gist.github.com/SirLouen/6c2b540d0f22d234cc9a4df9e3c5bf26

But after running it, also ends with a ton of chrome defunct processes

Conclusion: Question is unresolved, but in case somewhere finds this issue, I leave my results. There might be a bug somewhere in the puppeteer under these conditions. I will be reporting in their bug tracker.